# Allow User to Draw Rectangle on Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to let the user draw a rectangle on Google Maps by clicking on a button and then adding the rectangle to the map that they can then resize/drag. As far as I know, Google's API doesn't allow us to let the user click and drag the mouse cursor across the map to draw the rectangle, so I think we have to use initial/starting bounds?

I am getting an error (see my JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/58ZuT/)) when I click on the event handler responsible for drawing the rectangle:

```
rectangle.setMap(map);
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function() {
    addRecPath();
});
```

I've been trying to create how to let the users draw a rectangle based on the tutorials provided by Google [here (polylines)](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/polyline-complex) and [here (user-editable shapes)](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/user-editable-shapes).

Where am I going wrong? It seems like the problem is the event handler. Can (or should) this rectangle be pushed inside an array?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Things you are missing

1. Need to initialize google drawing Maps API library.
2. Need to initialize drawing Manager Object to draw Shapes.

Follow [the tutorial](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/drawing-tools) for your reference.

> NO. You dont have to use initial/starting bounds to draw a shape in google maps. Google provides Google drawing API to allow users to draw a shapes. You can use any shapes.(Polygon, Polyline, circle, rectangle)

Please go through the following [demo](http://jsbin.com/harawira/1/edit).

**JS**

```
var map;
var drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager();

function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(44.5452, -78.5389),
        zoom: 9
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
    mapOptions);
}

function drawRec() {
        //Setting options for the Drawing Tool. In our case, enabling Polygon shape.
        drawingManager.setOptions({
            drawingMode : google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.RECTANGLE,
            drawingControl : true,
            drawingControlOptions : {
                position : google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER,
                drawingModes : [ google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.RECTANGLE ]
            },
            rectangleOptions : {
                strokeColor : '#6c6c6c',
                strokeWeight : 3.5,
                fillColor : '#926239',
                fillOpacity : 0.6,
                editable: true,
                draggable: true
            }   
        });
        // Loading the drawing Tool in the Map.
        drawingManager.setMap(map);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

**HTML**

```
<button onclick="drawRec();">Draw Rectangle</button>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&libraries=drawing"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks ArunRaj. Do I have to use the Drawing Manager? Can I not simply use `new google.maps.Rectangle`? By the way, the demo link actually links to the JSFiddle from my post.

Comment: @kolor : I am sorry, In the demo I was tried update your code. Now Check it again. To draw a Shape, You must have to use Drawing Manger. To control a events on a drawn shape you can use Rectangle (eg : giving a name to each rectangle shapes) . Actually Without rectangle object you can do it. For start up,  I am giving you an example.

Comment: Ok, I can see the demo now. Thank you for your help. I am still wondering the advantage of using the drawing manager. I never thought of it doing this way. In the past I've tried using `new google.maps.Polygon`, `new google.maps.Circle`, `new google.maps.Rectangle`, etc. Can you still catch coordinates of the drawn features using the drawing manager?

Comment: @kolor : Yes you can do anything for your spatial application requirement.

Better put up another question, I will help you by brief it. That will help many people too.

Comment: Good idea. I would like to see a discussion on it. My question is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23026537/google-maps-drawing-library-vs-standard-drawing-techniques